# Snake and Ladder game stuck after 3 plays

Tags: python

I have been trying to implement the logic , when player rolled dice 3 times continues `6` then reset his score to initial old score before he rolled the dice to `6`.

**For example :**

```
Player 1 -> Dice : 6  -> Score -> 6   -> First  time 6 occurred on Dice 
Player 1 -> Dice : 6  -> Score -> 12  -> Second time 6 occurred on Dice 
Player 1 -> Dice : 6  -> Score -> 0   -> Third  time 6 occurred on Dice [ reset to old score ]
```

**What I tried to implement**

```
        old_score.append(ply1)

        if dice_rolled_ply_1 == 6:

            flag = 0 

            sum_of_six = sum_of_six + dice_rolled_ply_1

            if sum_of_six == 18:
                player_1_score = old_score[0]
                print(
                    {
                        "PLAYER 1 ": lst_of_palyers[i],
                        "DICE ": dice_rolled_ply_1,
                        "SCORE ": player_1_score,
                        "RESET TO OLD SCORE ": "PLAYER 1",
                    }
                )
                old_score.clear()
                flag = 1
```

**My Main Full code of GAME :**

```
import random
import time
import sys
import copy

lst_of_palyers = ['Vikas','Vamsh']

# LADDER FOR PLAYERS
powerupladder = {4: 56, 12: 50, 14: 55, 22: 58, 41: 79, 54: 88}
powerupladder_ply_1 = copy.deepcopy(powerupladder)
powerupladder_ply_2 = copy.deepcopy(powerupladder)

# SNAKE FOR PLAYERS
snakes = {37: 3, 47: 16, 28: 10, 96: 42, 75: 32, 94: 71}

# PRE-DEFINED VARIABLES
flag = 0
i = 0
ply1 = 0
ply2 = 0
maxCnt = 100
player_1_score = 0
player_2_score = 0
sum_of_six = 0
status = 1
old_score = []

if status == 1:

    # Storing the player name in sequence to play
    for k, v in who_starts.items():
        lst_of_palyers.append(k)

    while True:

        if flag == 0:

            # dice_rolled_ply_1 = random.randint(1, 6)
            dice_rolled_ply_1 = 6

            player_1_score = ply1 + dice_rolled_ply_1
            old_score.append(ply1)

            if dice_rolled_ply_1 == 6:

                flag = 0 

                sum_of_six = sum_of_six + dice_rolled_ply_1

                if sum_of_six == 18:
                    player_1_score = old_score[0]
                    print(
                        {
                            "PLAYER 1 ": lst_of_palyers[i],
                            "DICE ": dice_rolled_ply_1,
                            "SCORE ": player_1_score,
                            "RESET TO OLD SCORE ": "PLAYER 1",
                        }
                    )
                    old_score.clear()
                    flag = 1

            else:

                # Snake checking
                if player_1_score in snakes:

                    ply1 = snakes[player_1_score]
                    del snakes[player_1_score]
                    player_1_score = ply1
                    print(
                        {
                            "PLAYER 1 ": lst_of_palyers[i],
                            "DICE ": dice_rolled_ply_1,
                            "SCORE ": player_1_score,
                            "OOP's YOU GOT A SNAKE ": "PLAYER 1",
                        }
                    )
                    flag = 1

                else:

                    if player_1_score in powerupladder_ply_1:
                        ply1 = powerupladder_ply_1[player_1_score]
                        del powerupladder_ply_1[player_1_score]
                        player_1_score = ply1
                        print(
                            {
                                "PLAYER 1 ": lst_of_palyers[i],
                                "DICE ": dice_rolled_ply_1,
                                "SCORE ": player_1_score,
                                "YOU GOT A LADDER , PLAY AGAIN ": "PLAYER 1",
                            }
                        )
                        flag = 0

                    else:

                        ply1 = ply1 + dice_rolled_ply_1
                        print(
                            {
                                "PLAYER 1 ": lst_of_palyers[i],
                                "DICE ": dice_rolled_ply_1,
                                "SCORE ": player_1_score,
                            }
                        )
                        flag = 1

        else:

            dice_rolled_ply_2 = random.randint(1, 6)

            player_2_score = ply2 + dice_rolled_ply_2
            old_score.append(ply2)

            if dice_rolled_ply_2 == 6:
              
              flag=1
              
              sum_of_six = sum_of_six + dice_rolled_ply_2

              if sum_of_six == 18:
                    player_2_score = old_score[0]
                    print(
                        {
                            "PLAYER 2 ": lst_of_palyers[i + 1],
                            "DICE ": dice_rolled_ply_2,
                            "SCORE ": player_2_score,
                            "RESET TO OLD SCORE ": "PLAYER 2",
                        }
                    )
                    old_score.clear()
                    flag = 0

            else:

                # Snake checking
                if player_2_score in snakes:
                    ply2 = snakes[player_2_score]
                    del snakes[player_2_score]
                    player_2_score = ply2
                    print(
                        {
                            "PLAYER 2 ": lst_of_palyers[i + 1],
                            "DICE ": dice_rolled_ply_2,
                            "SCORE ": player_2_score,
                            "OOP's YOU GOT A SNAKE ": "PLAYER 2",
                        }
                    )
                    flag = 0

                else:

                    if player_2_score in powerupladder_ply_2:
                        ply2 = powerupladder_ply_2[player_2_score]
                        del powerupladder_ply_2[player_2_score]
                        player_2_score = ply2
                        print(
                            {
                                "PLAYER 2 ": lst_of_palyers[i + 1],
                                "DICE ": dice_rolled_ply_2,
                                "SCORE ": player_2_score,
                                "YOU GOT A LADDER , PLAY AGAIN ": "PLAYER 2",
                            }
                        )
                        flag = 1
                    else:
                        ply2 = ply2 + dice_rolled_ply_2
                        print(
                            {
                                "PLAYER 2 ": lst_of_palyers[i + 1],
                                "DICE ": dice_rolled_ply_2,
                                "SCORE ": player_2_score,
                            }
                        )
                        flag = 0

        if ply1 >= maxCnt:
            print("")
            print(
                f"CONGRATULATIONS , {lst_of_palyers[i]} YOU WON THE GAME BY SCORING : {ply1}  & YOUR COMPETITOR {lst_of_palyers[i+1]} LOSE GAME BY SCORING : {ply2}"
            )
            break
        elif ply2 >= maxCnt:
            print("")
            print(
                f"CONGRATULATIONS , {lst_of_palyers[i+1]} YOU WON THE GAME BY SCORING : {ply2}  & YOUR COMPETITOR {lst_of_palyers[i]} LOSE GAME BY SCORING : {ply1}"
            )
            break
        else:
            pass
else:

    pass
```

**Currently may game is not moving further after 3 steps**

```
{'PLAYER 1 ': 'Vamsh', 'DICE ': 6, 'SCORE ': 0, 'RESET TO OLD SCORE ': 'PLAYER 1'}
{'PLAYER 2 ': 'Vikas', 'DICE ': 4, 'SCORE ': 56, 'YOU GOT A LADDER , PLAY AGAIN ': 'PLAYER 2'}
{'PLAYER 2 ': 'Vikas', 'DICE ': 4, 'SCORE ': 60}
```

Any fix for it is much appreciated !!!

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is for questions about [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news).

Answer (score 0):

In what you tried to implement, when player 1 rolls a 6 three times, you reset his score and change players, but you do not reset the sum_of_six variable.

Furthermore, in your sample code, player 1 always rolls a six.

As a result, when it is player 1's turn again, sum_of_six is not 18 (it's 24), so you do not print any output and it is player 1's turn over and over again. Since "dice_rolled" is always 6 and "sum_of_six" is never 18, you do not print anything and the program runs in an infinite loop.

At the very least, you need to reset sum_of_six in the case it is 18. Also, if any player rolls a 6, I think they should move along the board and update their score in the same way as if they rolls between 1 and 5, should they not ?

Comment: Yes you said right let me try to reset sum and score update